# C++ -- Questions about "protected inheritance"

Tags: c++

I assume that I understand the meaning of "protected inheritance". However, after discussing this issue with one folk here, I feel a little confused now.

Here is my understanding of "protected inheritance" in c++

Assume the following class structure.

```
class Base {}
class SubClass : protected Base {}
```

1> If a subclass is defined as "protected BaseClass", then this subclass is no longer a subclass of the BaseClass. Instead, the BaseClass only serves as a utility tool for the subclass. In other word, if you cast SubClass* to Base*, SubClass& to Base&, or SubClass to Base, you should expect an error.

2> The major reason why people use protected inheritance is that the expected SubClass is NOT a subclass of the Base (For example, Car is not a subclass of Engine). While, in the same time, SubClass wants to call the functions defined in the Base class.

3> There is a good reason sometimes you prefer to using protected inheritance rather than define a member variable as an object of the Base. (but I don't remember in which case).

Please correct my comments if I am wrong.

thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between private, public and protected inheritance in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For 1. - `SubClass` is still a subclass of `Base`.  Protected inheritance is still inheritance.  You are correct that automatic conversion from `SubClass` to `Base` is not possible, though.

```
SubClass sub;
Base* base(&sub);
```

gives

> error C2243: 'type cast' : conversion
>   from 'SubClass *' to 'Base *' exists,
>   but is inaccessible

For 2. and 3. - the major reason people want this is to hide `public/protected` members of `Base` from **clients** of `SubClass`.  **Subclasses** of `SubClass` CAN still see them.  Contrast this with `private` inheritance which hides `Base` completely from **subclasses and clients** of `SubClass` - this would also meet your criteria in the last sentence of 2, but disallow **any** other external use of `Base` via `SubClass`.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably heard these terms from OO discussion, IS-A (public inheritance) HAS-A (contains).  I've heard this term for protected or private inheritance "IMPLEMENTED-AS-A".  For example, you may implement a Stack class AS-AN Array, but you don't want the public methods of Array be exposed to the clients of Stack.

As you pointed out, you could implement a stack using an array as a data member.